# Pipelines in BASH causing lost connections with db2

Tags: bash, db2

```
# it works fine
db2 connect to <db_name> user <user> using <passwd>
while read aline
do
    tab=$(echo $aline | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
    col=$(echo $aline | awk -F',' '{print $2}')
    max_id=$(db2 -x "select count($col) from $tab")
    echo $tab   $col   $max_id
done < tab.ls


# it doesn't work because of lost DB connection
db2 connect to <db_name> user <user> using <passwd>
cat tab.lst | while read aline
do
    tab=$(echo $aline | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
    col=$(echo $aline | awk -F',' '{print $2}')
    max_id=$(db2 -x "select count($col) from $tab")
    echo $tab   $col   $max_id
done
```

I have two parts of codes, both have just little differences, the 1st part run as expected, but the 2nd did not.

It seems that pipelines caused losing DB connections.

Can anyone explain why.

Thanks in advance!

BTW: I tested in RH Linux 6.6, bash

Comment: The multiple calls to `awk` are wasteful and unnecessary; `while IFS=, read -r tab col other; do max_id=$(...); echo ...; done < tab.ls`. If you know that each line from `tab.ls` only consists of two fields, you can drop the 3rd argument `other` whose only purpose is to make sure that `col` is the 2nd column only.

Comment: Thank you so much！It‘s quit helpful！

Answer (score 0):

DB2 [documentation](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/accdb/z0438366.htm) says:

> You can connect to only one DB2 database at a time; however, you can
>   use multiple CONNECT statements to connect to multiple DB2 data
>   sources by using the alias argument to distinguish your connections.

In your example above, you are connecting twice. Consider resetting or terminating your connection:

```
db2 connection reset
```

or

```
db2 terminate
```